# Rewrite by removing duplicate if found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

My current `.htaccess` looks like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# / = /home
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?r=home [QSA,L]

# /example/ = /example
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]


# request, but not pointing to an existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

# pass the whole request as a variable
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?r=$1 [QSA]
```

After these rewrites are done, I'd like to make sure that the URL doesn't end up having a duplicated part of a path at the end.
Here are a few test cases to more clearly demonstrate what I'd like to accomplish:

```
domain.tld/example                // No more rewrites
domain.tld/example/example        // Rewrite to domain.tld/example
domain.tld/test/example/example   // Rewrite to domain.tld/test/example
domain.tld/example/test/test/test // Rewrite to domain.tld/example/test/test
```

So basically, if the last part of the URL is same as the penultimate, then remove the last part.

I've managed to put together this regex:

```
\/(.+)\/{1}\1$
```

which seems to match any duplicated parts of the URL, but I don't know if this is quite right for my needs, or how to implement the actual URL rewrite itself.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that I can use the following `RewriteRule` to accomplish this.

```
RewriteRule (.+)\/\1$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What's the purpose of `{1}`?

Comment: Ah, I think that's just a leftover from when I was figuring out the right pattern. Seems it's useless, I'll edit it out.